# Amazon EC2 Domain Host

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cross-domain, hosting

I am running a Amazon EC2 instance for my personal website. I am using WordPress, Apache2.4 and PHP5.5 as the back-end.

Suppose the elastic IP address for my server is `1.2.3.4` and my domain is `www.mydomain.com`.  I have purchased a domain on `http://www.domain.com`and pointed the URL to `1.2.3.4/wordpress`

My problem is that, when I type `www.mydomain.com` in the browser, the address is not `www.mydomain.com/wordpress` but instead `1.2.3.4/wordpress`.

I have added `127.0.0.1 mydomain.com` in `/etc/hosts`
and I have added:

```
Listen 80
<virtualHost 1.2.3.4>
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerName www.mydomain.com
```

in `/etv/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

But this doesn't work.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: This does not work for Apache2.4

Comment: Please expand on "not work".  Describe what happens, including any error messages or trace you get.